# Short vibrations instead of turning on

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

My smartphone is giving out short regular vibrations instead of turning on. It's the same kind of vibration that usually goes with turning on or off the device.

The smartphone is rooted and I can access the clockworkmod menu to save or recover system images.

What may be the cause of this problem? Is it hardware or software related?

Comment: Give more details please. Like when did it start happening? Anything particular you did that started causing this? And what phone do you have? Are you using custom ROM? And any other relevant details...

Comment: I can't imagine anything specific, I just found it in that condition when I woke up. The phone is a Galaxy Ace 3, rooted, with a stock rom. Also, I'll need to find an external battery charger before attempting anything because the phone is not charging the battery (not even while shut off). I suspect there may be some contact in the USB port, but I'm quite clueless in fact.